# Custom PHP API, JSON Response and Xamarin JSON Parsing

Tags: c#, php, json, api, xamarin

I have built my own custom PHP API which should returns a JSON response built with data from my database.
My Android app should read and parse the content of the response and put it on a ListView

I have googled a lot and did much of it. But in my opinion the JSON Response design I created is wrong.

```
//Function prints a multidimensional array ($return_array) on page
    $return_array = array();

    if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT `id`, `username`, `longitude`, `latitude` FROM `location` WHERE `username` = ?")){

        $stmt -> bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($id, $username, $longitude, $latitude);

        while($stmt -> fetch()){

            $local_array = array(); //Not sure if this is neccessary but i'll keep it

            $local_array[] = array(
                'ID'=>$id, 
                'Username'=>$username, 
                'Longitude'=>$longitude, 
                'Latitude'=>$latitude
                );

            array_push($return_array, $local_array);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($return_array);
```

Data gets downloaded and fetched. The JSON Response looks like this.
[image]

I don't know much about JSON Responses, but my Googling skills told me that this is wrong.

This is how I JSON Response. (Xamarin C#)

```
private async Task<JsonValue> selectFromApi() {
        string url = "http://192.168.43.126/api.php?download=true&username=admin&submit=Submit";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync()) {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));

                return jsonDoc;
            }
        }
    }
```

So I have no code to show you how I parse the response because nothing worked.
Finally my question, how do I correctly display the JSON response? What do I have to add/modify?

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT:

My model looks like this

```
namespace DatabaseManager {
    class LocationModel {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is how I deserialize theresponse.

```
var data = await selectFromApi();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LocationModel>>(data);
```

This is the error

```
04-24 20:18:26.029 I/mono-stdout(25426): -------------START FAIL--------------
04-24 20:18:26.038 I/mono-stdout(25426): System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
04-24 20:18:26.038 I/mono-stdout(25426):   at System.Json.JsonValue.op_Implicit (System.Json.JsonValue value) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/System.Json/System.Json/JsonValue.cs:438 
04-24 20:18:26.038 I/mono-stdout(25426):   at DatabaseManager.MainActivity+<OnCreate>d__0.MoveNext () [0x000ba] in C:\Users\xNULL\Desktop\SoulmeetModules\DatabaseManagement\DatabaseManager\DatabaseManager\MainActivity.cs:23 
04-24 20:18:26.038 I/mono-stdout(25426): -------------END FAIL--------------
```

Comment: generally, the best practice for doing this would be to create a C# model and deserialize your json into a List<Model> (or other IEnumerable) and then bind that to your ListView

Comment: @Jason I already have a model but deserializing is not working. The app keeps crashing.

Comment: then post your model and the details of the exception that is causing the crash.

Comment: @Jason Added as EDIT

Comment: you json appears to be an array within an array - try removing the outer array from your PHP, or try using List<List<Model>> when deserializing

Comment: I don't think that the parsing appears to be the issue. Is the JSON response okay?

Comment: you posted your JSON as an image so I can't verify it.  There are multiple free online tools that will check it for you.  As I already noted, your JSON appears to have a nested array "[[" structure that your model does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142649/discussion-between-manuel-burge-and-jason).